# Dynamically Add buttons below ListView items in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-listview

I am trying to dynamically create a `button` below a ListView Item when the item is clicked.

Below is an example of my ListView before and after the items are clicked

**Before:**

---

Item1

---

Item2

---

Item3

---

**After Item 2 is clicked:**

---

Item1

---

Item2

`[Text] [Text] [Button]`

---

Item3

---

How to dynamically add a row of text Items and buttons below clicked listview item?

Comment: have these button in list_view_row.xml in invisible state, once you click on item , call setnotifydataset change and in getView() method of your adapter change the state of button to visible.

Comment: how about showing us your efforts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [library](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView), it's gives you what you want.

Add this to your `list_item.xml` as mentioned in library documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="Hello World"/>

    <!-- this is the button that will trigger sliding of the expandable view -->
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/expandable_toggle_button"
            android:text="More"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- this is the expandable view that is initially hidden and will slide out when the more button is pressed -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:background="#000000">

    <!-- put whatever you want in the expandable view -->
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Action A" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Action B"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this to your `activity`:

```
ListView list = ... your list view
    ListAdapter adapter = ... your list adapter
    // now simply wrap the adapter
    // and indicate the ids of your toggle button
    // and expandable view
    list.setAdapter(new SlideExpandableListAdapter(
            adapter,
            R.id.expandable_toggle_button,
            R.id.expandable
        )
    );
```

Comment: other options are available. No need to use library for small purposes!

Comment: Just suggest and he have the choice!

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom layout for your list item. Set a Linear layout over there and set in invisible state. Then you can add views over there by making it visible. Call setnotifydatachanged in your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `ExpandableListView`. When you click on parent item then expend a child view show on below of parent. And you can add any view on to child.

And you can check the following [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) to implement expendable view.